# Can I extend a Tensorflow Estimator to also return the explanation values?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-estimator

I have a model built by following roughly [the tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/estimator/boosted_trees) provided for the `tf.estimator.BoostedTreesClassifier` in the docs. I then exported it by using the `tf.Estimator.export_saved_model` method as described in the [SavedModels from Estimators](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#savedmodels_from_estimators) section of the SavedModel docs. This loads in to TensorFlow Serving and answers gRPC and REST requests.

I'd now like to include the explanation factors along with any predictions. Or, less ideally, as a second signature available on the exported model. `tf.estimator._BoostedTreesBase.experimental_predict_with_explanations` already implements an appropriate algorithm, as described in [Local Interpretability](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/estimator/boosted_trees_model_understanding#local_interpretability) section of the docs.

I thought it would be possible to 'extend' the existing estimator in a way that would let me expose this method as another served signature. I've thought of several approaches, but only tried the first two so far:

## I've Tried

#### Change which signatures `export_saved_model` exports

This didn't go very far. The exposed signatures are a little dynamic, but seem to be limited to the train, predict or eval options defined by `tensorflow_core.python.saved_model.model_utils.mode_keys.KerasModeKeys`.

#### Just use an `eval_savedmodel`?

I briefly thought Eval might be what I was looking for, and followed some of the [getting started guide](https://github.com/tensorflow/model-analysis/blob/master/g3doc/get_started.md) for TensorFlow Model Analysis. The further I go on this path the more it seems like the main difference with an Eval model is how the data is loaded, and that isn't what I want to change.

#### Subclass the estimator

There are extra caveats with [exporting subclassed models](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#saving_subclassed_models). And on top of that an Estimator isn't a Model. It's a model with extra metadata around inputs, outputs and configuration, so I am not clear if a subclassed estimator would even be exportable in the same way a Keras Model is.

I abandoned this subclassing approach without writing much code.

#### Pull the BoostedTrees Model out of the Estimator

I am not savvy enough to arrange a BoostedTrees model myself, using the low-level primitives. The code in the Estimator that sets it up looks fairly complex. It would be nice to leverage that work, but it seems that the Estimator deals in `model_fn`s, they change depending on the train/predict/eval mode, and it isn't clear what the relationship to a Keras Model is.

I wrote a little code for this, but also gave up on it quickly.

## What Next?

Given the above dead ends, which angle should I be persuing further?

Both the [low-level export API](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#identifying_a_signature_to_export), and the low-level model building API look like they could get me closer to a solution. The gap between setting up an Estimator, and re-creating one using either API seems fairly wide.

Is it possible I could continue using the existing Estimator, but use the low-level export API to create something with an "interpret" signature that calls through to `experimental_predict_with_explanations`? Or even "predict and interpret" in a single step? Which tutorial will put me on that path?